# How to separate gsub results into two lists in R?

Tags: r, list, gsub

I'm using gsub in R to extract some text from html code. Right now the results are showing up as a list, with the two pieces of text separated by a space because of the "\1 \2".

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
results <- gsub("...(.+)...(.+)...", "\\1 \\2", data)
```

Is there a separator I can put between the `\\1` and `\\2` that would give me the results in two separate lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to save two different capture groups into different objects you can split the `results` on the space and capture the two parts differently.

```
results <- gsub("...(.+)...(.+)...", "\\1 \\2", data)
results <- strsplit(results, ' ')[[1]]
a <- results[1]
b <- results[2]
```